# GTK2 themes do not show up in any tweak tool

Tags: 14.04, unity, themes, unity-tweak-tool

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I would like to download this [theme](http://jurialmunkey.deviantart.com/art/Divergence-IV-quot-A-New-Hope-quot-183377193)

I managed to get it to work on 13.10 but since I upgraded to 14.04 it no longer works. When I look in any tweak tool it does not show up. Other themes that I copied into ~/.themes and also /usr/share/themes work just fine. The only difference as far as I can tell is those themes that work have both a gtk-2.0 and a gtk-3.0 folder, while this theme "A New Hope" only has a gtk-2.0 folder.

edit: Well, I guess the theme is just not gtk3 compatible, is the answer. But is there any way around this?